# Application that allows you to customize which keys to use for mousekeys

Tags: macos, mouse-keys

Is there an application for customizing mouse-keys, specifically choosing which keys to use?

I don't have a numpad so I can't use the built-in mouse-keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predefined settings in KeyRemap4MacBook aren't really usable, but you can add custom settings by creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

[image]

See the source for the [virtual keycode constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and the [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true).